# How to load jquery file in codeigniter controller (not the codeigniter jquery class)

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Please see this link: http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/364-answered-set-relation-and-add-new-button-to-quick-insert/

I am trying to do something like this. My view file is like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".various").fancybox();

//ADD IN A BUTTON TO ADD TO DROPDOWN
$('#countryID_input_box').append('<a href="<?=site_url()?>/examples/quick_add/" class="various fancybox.ajax">Add</a>');
});
</script>
```

And controller:

```
    function quick_add()
{
  //EDIT BELOW TO ADD YOU SELECT NAME VALUE
  $args = array(
'category_name' => 'select[name="countryID"]'
  );

  $javascript = '
  <script>
  function do_quick_add()
  {
var category_text = $(\'#category_item\').val();
var category_id = $(\''.$args['category_name'].'\').val();

$.post(\''.site_url().'/examples/quick_add_save/\', { categoryID: category_id, category_item: category_text }, function(data) {
//PREPEND DATA TO SELECT BOX
$(\''.$args['category_name'].'\').prepend(\'<option value="\'+data+\'">\'+category_text+\'</option>\');
//REBUILD SELECT BOX
$(\''.$args['category_name'].'\').trigger("liszt:updated");
//DISPLAY SUCCESS MESSAGE
$(\'#category_message\').html(\'Successfully inserted a new category\');
});
  }
  </script>
  ';

  $html = '
  <div style="width: 400px; height: 250px;">
  <div style="padding: 5px;">New Category Name:</div>
  <div style="padding: 5px;"><input type="text" name="category_item" id="category_item"></div>
  <div style="padding: 5px;"><input type="button" value="Add &raquo;" onclick="do_quick_add();"> <span id="category_message"></span></div>
  </div>
  ';

  echo $javascript.$html;
  exit;
}

function quick_add_save()
{
//POST ITEMS
$categoryID = $this->input->post('categoryID', true); //only needed if adding a sub category, can get parent ID
$category_text = $this->input->post('category_item', true);

//SAVE TO DATABASE
$data = array(
'country_title' => $category_text
);
$this->db->insert('country', $data);

return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

I loaded the jquery file:

```
$includes_url = APPPATH.'jquery/jquery.min.js';
$this->load->file($includes_url);
```

But after doing all these I am getting:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

The "Add" button comes, fancybox loads but in fancybox when I try to post by clicking "Add" nothing happens.

Comment: echo-ing around the html in the controller kills the use of MVC frameworks :/

Comment: Will you please explain what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".various").fancybox();
var site_url ='<?=site_url()?>'; // store that variable for js
//ADD IN A BUTTON TO ADD TO DROPDOWN
$('#countryID_input_box').append('<a href="'+site_url+'" class="various fancybox.ajax">Add</a>');
});
</script>
```